# Angular addValidator function doesn't immediately work, only after entering value into field and deleting it after

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using a reactive form with some fields and a toggle button:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
reminderForm: FormGroup;
public emailReminderType : boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void 
{
this.emailReminderType = false;

this.reminderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  Message: ["", Validators.required],
  EmailAddress: [""],
  DateWhenToSend: [""],
  TimeWhenToSend: [""],
});
}
```

and on clicking on toggle element, an event fires that sets a boolean value to either true or false. In this case, when it sets is to true, the email field needs to have validation.

HTML:

```
<mat-slide-toggle id="switchRemindEmail" (click)="onCheckboxEmailChange($event)">Via Email</mat-slide-toggle>
```

TS:

```
onCheckboxEmailChange(e) {
if (this.emailReminderType === false) {
  this.emailReminderType = true;
  this.reminderForm.get("EmailAddress").addValidators(Validators.required);
} else {
  this.emailReminderType = false;
  this.reminderForm.get("EmailAddress").clearValidators();
   }
}
```

and finally, the form submit button:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="reminderForm.valid && emailReminderType ? false : true">Remind me!</button>
```

The problem is, once I click on toggle, the submit button is still enabled even though the Email input field is empty. If I write something into the field and then delete it, only THEN becomes the button disabled.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the validation taking effect immediately after setting validation with 'addValidators' ?

Comment: just call `EmailAddress.updateValueAndValidity();` after addin the validator, and everything should work fine

Comment: @Andrei that solved it, thank you!